# Incorrect tooltip for Meta in footer

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tooltips, footer

The tooltip when hovering "Meta Stack Overflow" in the footer is right now:

> the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites

Proof just in case it's fixed:

> [image]

It appears that other sites' tooltip is taken from their About page e.g. [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) where the formula is:

```
[site name] is a question and answer site for [target audience]. It's built and run by you...
```

And the tooltip is taking the [target audience] of the site.

According to this logic, it can be the following for this Meta site:

> meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites

Comment: As a side note, all of the tooltips in the "Other" category (with the exception of Careers, which lacks a tooltip) describe the subject matter/purpose of the site, instead of the audience.

Comment: @Tim true, but only for Meta it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How so? Meta's topic is the Stack Exchange engine itself, from either the technical or community perspective.

Comment: @Tim from the tooltip it appears that Meta **is** the engine poweing Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it with the other devs it appears you are right and Meta is **not** the engine that powers these sites.

Tooltip fixed, disaster averted.

Comment: Wow that was fast, even for you!

Comment: White you're at it, Careers got no tooltip at all so unless it's on purpose... ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - yeah, that one is on purpose